# Shadow not showing on CarouselView Item

Tags: c#, xaml, carousel, maui

I have this little test project to explore MAUI. I want to have a `CarouselView` showing `Border` `Label` with a shadow.
My Carousel and its 10 test items are correctly rendered but not the shadow.

Note that I have no shadow at all on Windows, and a cropped shadow on Android (I suspect some layout cropping even though I added some margin).
I added a test item outside of the `CarouselView` underneath and shadow is working correctly.

Here is a little GIF animation of my test project running on Android : [image]

The code itself :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CarouselTest"
         x:DataType="vm:CarouselVM"
         x:Class="CarouselTest.MainPage"
         Title="CAROUSEL TEST">
         
<ScrollView>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="LightCoral">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>                
            <RowDefinition Height="410"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="310"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>          
        <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding CarouselTexts}" IndicatorView="indic"
                      HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="400"
                      Loop="False" BackgroundColor="PaleGoldenrod">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="10,0,10,10" Stroke="Gray" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300"
                            Background="WhiteSmoke" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5">
                        <Border.Shadow>
                            <Shadow Brush="Black" Offset="10,10" Radius="20" Opacity="0.9"/>
                        </Border.Shadow>
                        <Label Text="{Binding}" TextColor="DarkBlue" FontSize="72" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>            
        <IndicatorView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" IndicatorSize="22" IndicatorsShape="Circle"
                       IndicatorColor="Gainsboro" SelectedIndicatorColor="#006EFF"
                       x:Name="indic" />            
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,10" Stroke="Gray" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300"
                Background="WhiteSmoke" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5">
            <Border.Shadow>
                <Shadow Brush="Black" Offset="10,10" Radius="20" Opacity="0.9"/>
            </Border.Shadow>
            <Label Text="TEST" TextColor="Red" FontSize="72" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>            
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'd try putting the Border inside of another container like a StackLayout to see if that makes any difference

Comment: @Jason Thanks. Sorry for late answer, I add to switch to do something else meanwhile. So yeah using a container work to display Shadow ! Though I found different display of my carousel items between (Vertical/Horizontal)StakLayout where all item are close to each other like before using a container, and Grid where all item occupy whole screen (and that was the behavior I wanted, so nice side effect ;) ).